# How to handle Typescript imports with VS Code using Nativescript files (.tns)

Tags: typescript, configuration, visual-studio-code, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to use VS Code for a Nativescript project and having a terrible time with the imports.  It seems that VS Code uses the tsconfig file to resolve its typescript import statements.  However, in a standard Nativescript app the tsconfig file excludes **/*.tns.ts files.  Their intention is that the tsconfig files is used for the web app and the tsconfig.tns.ts file replaces it during the build process.

Since VS Code bases its import decisions on the tsconfig file, not the tsconfig.tns.ts file, and since .tns.ts files are excluded in the tsconfig, any path that isn't an absolute path shows up red.  ALL of our absolute paths like "@MyApp/..." show up red in .tns.ts files and intellisense cant pick up on anything imported via those "broken" imports.  However, these imports actually DO work after the build because Nativescript replaces tsconfig with tsconfig.tns.  This means we don't get to find out if an import statement is broken until after a build process, which is EXTREMELY time consuming.  It also means our files are littered with imports that show up underlined red which leads other team members to investigate "issues" that don't actually exist.

Is there any way to configure VS Code recognize Typescript imports in .tns.ts files?

Comment: You should add your comments to https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12463

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've added a comment to that thread.  Unfortunately, seeing all those other comments leads me to believe this issue can't be solved in VS Code right now...

Comment: i think youre doing something wrong, ive never had this issue in over 2 years

Comment: You can have multiple tsconfig files, it's most common requirement. Even in Angular web the default CLI template give you a different tsconfig for E2E tests which will only include files and typings related to E2E specs. Similarly you have `tsconfig.tns.json` in {N} Angular projects which should pickup the settings specific to {N} (.tns.ts) files.